# Master Method and use cases

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

$T(n)=T(n-2)+n^{2}$ and $T(n)=4T(n-2)+n^{2}$

Master method to solve these two equations?  I know I can use the other cases where $a$ and $b > 0$ but since $T(n-2)$ do I assume $b$ is $1$?

Comment: You don't need the Master theorem to solve these. Expand a few iterations to see the pattern and distinguish between $n$ even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the generating function to solve this problem. Generally, you can work on this problem: $T(n)=bT(n-2)+n^2$. (Letting $b=1$, you get the first and letting $b=4$, you get the second).  In fact, let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T(n)x^n$. Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x)&=&\sum_{n=0}^\infty T(n)x^n\\
&=&T(0)+T(1)x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty T(n)x^n\\
&=&T(0)+T(1)x+\sum_{n=0}^\infty T(n+2)x^{n+2}\\
&=&T(0)+T(1)x+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (bT(n)+(n+2)^2)x^{n+2}\\
&=&T(0)+T(1)x+bx^2f(x)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)^2x^{n+2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Since
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)^2x^{n+2}\\
&=&x(\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+2)x^{n+2})'\\
&=&x(x+x\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1})'\\
&=&x(x+x\frac{1}{(1-x)^2})'.
\end{eqnarray*}
From this, it is easy to get $f(z)$. By Taylor expansion, one can $T(n)$. For I omit the detail.